# PHP/CURL/Other - How resource intensive?

Tags: php, resources, curl, curl-multi

I am going to have a daemon that will run on a FreeBSD server, which will exchange small amounts of data with a list of URIs every minute.

I am thinking to use the curl_multi functions to run them all at once, or in groups, every minute, using a post.  I am open to other ideas though.

I will have to do some benchmarking later on, but for now, does anyone know how resource intensive it is to make many small posts with curl?

Is there a less intensive way to do this?  SOAP perhaps?  To start, there will only be a few every minute, but it may grow quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that SOAP processing (generating query, sending it, get it processed then getting answer back) may be more resource intensive than just a POST, even "multithreaded".  Profiling or benchmarking is probably the only way to be sure anyway.